# C Char Array missing full values after going through a function

Tags: arrays, c

I am learning C. I thought it would be a fun exercise to create a function that creates Ceasar cipher

```
int caesarcypher(char x[], char y[], int n) {
    printf("Original Message: %s\n", x);
    size_t al= sizeof(alph) / sizeof(alph[0]);
    size_t ml = strlen(x);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < ml;i++) {
        for (size_t z = 0; z < al;z++) {
            if (x[i] == alph[z]) {
                if (z + n > al) {
                    size_t wrap = z + n - al;
                    y[i] = alph[wrap];
                }
                else {
                    y[i] = alph[z + 3];
                }

            }
            else if (x[i]==" ") {
                y[i] = " ";
            }

        }

    }
    printf("Coded Message: %s\n",y);
    return 0;
};
```

to this function I pass value x, the message, and value y, the char[] where the coded message will appear. however, when I run it I end up with something like this

```
Original Message: this message is a secret
Coded Message: wklv
```

it ciphers "this" the way I want it to, but why is the rest of the string not appearing?

edit:
the code that would appear outside the function would be:

```
char alph [] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

int main(void) {

    char ogmsg [100] = {0};
    char cdmsg [100]= {0};

    strcpy(ogmsg, "this is a secret message");
    caesarcypher(ogmsg, cdmsg, 3);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: `x[i]==" "` is unlikely ever to be true, because `" "` is a string literal, not a `char`.  You mean `x[i] == ' '`.  Similarly, you mean `y[i] = ' '`.

Comment: Your compiler really ought to be generating warnings about those, by the way.  Turn up the warning level if it isn't, and pay attention to the warnings it emits.  If you can't get it to warn then it would probably be worth your while to find a better compiler.

Comment: By the way, a more robust fix would be to skip the comparison altogether and simply say `else { y[i] = x[i]; }`.  That will handle all characters not appearing in `alph`, as opposed to space characters only.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I'll check about the warnings, it's visual studio so I should be able to do it. Do you happen to know why it would stop short instead of doing the rest of the characters? even if it doesn't detect the spaces I would expect the result to end up looking something like this "wklvlvdvhfuhwphvvdjh"

Comment: It would help to post a [mcve] so that other people can reproduce the problem.

Comment: When your code reaches a space character, it does not set the corresponding output character at all.  Ever.  Whatever character was initially at that position in the output buffer remains there, even as the function fills in later ones.  It looks like the output buffer contains a null byte at that position in your tests, which serves as a string terminator.

Comment: Note also that Visual Studio's is not a particularly good C compiler, but I nevertheless do expect that it could muster warnings for those particular issues.

Comment: @JohnBollinger VS spits out: `warning C4047: '==': 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'char [2]'` and `warning C4047: '=': 'char' differs in levels of indirection from 'char [2]'`